# DynamoDB Client.Scan() is not returning the LastEvaluatedKey parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table with 10k rows. 
I'm trying to parse them to change a small thing inside an attribute (inside each row) with Python, so I'm using the client.scan() taking batches of 10 rows and giving the "LastEvaluatedKey" parameter to the next .scan().

The problem is that after 40 rows the scan() doesn't return the lastKey, like the DB it's only 40 lines long.

I've noticed that launching the same script against another table, 3x times bigger, the stop happens at 120 rows (3x times bigger).

The table has On-Demand capacity.

Any idea about this?

```
client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
resource = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = resource.Table(table_name)

remaining = 3961
iteration = 0
limit = 10

while remaining > 0:
    # retrieve Limit
    if iteration == 0:
        response = client.scan(
            TableName=table_name,
            Limit=limit,
            Select='ALL_ATTRIBUTES',
            ReturnConsumedCapacity='TOTAL',
            TotalSegments=123,
            Segment=122,
        )
        key = response["LastEvaluatedKey"]
    else:

        response = client.scan(
            TableName=table_name,
            Limit=limit,
            Select='ALL_ATTRIBUTES',
            ExclusiveStartKey=key,
            ReturnConsumedCapacity='TOTAL',
            TotalSegments=123,
            Segment=122,
        )

        key = response["LastEvaluatedKey"]

    iteration += 1
    for el in response["Items"]:
        print(el)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two problems:

1. you seem to be scanning with a limit: try removing that
2. your are running a parallel scan and always scanning the last segment:

   TotalSegments=123
   Segment=122

I'm not sure how big your tables are but 123 segments is quite a lot and I don't see you scanning any of other segments, from 0 to 121.

---

Try this:

```
iteration = 0
response = client.scan(
    TableName=table_name,
    Select='ALL_ATTRIBUTES',
    ReturnConsumedCapacity='TOTAL'
)
while True:
    iteration += 1
    for el in response["Items"]:
        print(el)
    last_key = response["LastEvaluatedKey"]
    if not last_key: 
        break
    response = client.scan(
        TableName=table_name,
        Select='ALL_ATTRIBUTES',
        ExclusiveStartKey=last_key,
        ReturnConsumedCapacity='TOTAL'           
    )
```

I expect the above should work to retrieve all items in your table. Then, if you still would like to run a parallel scan, you can do so but you'll have to handle the splitting into segments and in order for that to be efficient you'll have to handle running those concurrently (more complicated to do than a sequential scan).

Comment: Thank you very much Mike, the problem was, in fact, the segment.

Comment: Great! If this answers your question consider accepting the answer